# ¿Cómo ver un proyecto de Laravel/Homestead en LAN?

Tags: laravel

Estoy usando Laravel/Homestead en linux mint para desarrollar y me gustaria ver como avanza el proyecto desde varios dispositivos en mi red LAN, intento ingresar desde otro pc con myapp.test pero no me puedo conectar.

Comment: Prueba con la IP y el puerto de la máquina donde está el servidor en la LAN. Por ejemplo, si tu máquina tiene una ip como `192.168.0.101` y el server escucha un puerto como `8080`, en tu otro dispositivo intenta acceder a `192.168.0.101:8080`

Comment: Lo acabo de intentar, pero solo funciona desde mi computadora, intento hacer desde mi telefono que esta conectado al wifi y no conecta.

Comment: Si no puedes acceder desde el virtual host que creaste, puedes usar `php artisan serve --host=your.ip.address --port=8080` y según la ip que hayas asignado, debería verse en otros dispositivos al colocarlas en la barra de navegación.

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes de asber tu ip que te asigna tu router (asegurate que los dispositivos esten conectados a la misma red es indiferente si es por cable o wifi), abre el terminal del equipo:

```
ifconfig (linux) 

ipconfig (windows)
```

despues de acuerdo al puerto que tengas configurado para acceder (44300 default), lo pones en tu dispotivo donde quieras visualizar tu proyecto junto con la direccion de tu equipo donde estas corriendo el proyecto.

> EJEMPLO:

```
http://192.168.0.10:44300

https://192.168.0.10:44300 (si te aparece "la conexión no es privada" es que si tenes acceso)
```